# Stacking boxes of different heights

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm attempting a non-standard layout w/ Bootstrap 3. The idea is to have something like this (yay, ASCII art!)

```
+---+---+-------+
| A | B |       |
+---+---+   C   |
| D | E |       |
+---+---+-------+
```

But my current layout shows something like this: (- = empty space)

```
+---+---+-------+
| A | B |       |
+---+---+   C   |
| - | - |       |
+---+---+-------+
| D | E |
+---+---+
```

Link: http://www.bootply.com/3m75xi0G2M

Can this be done in "pure" BS3? Supposedly, this can be done w/ Masonry, but since the site is already built w/ BS3, I'd rather stay away from additional frameworks.

(In this particular case, the larger column is on the right side. But some will be in the middle or even left - the real grid is done using a modified 10-grid bootstrap.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a wrapper for ABDE, make that wrapper col-6 and make C col-6.
This will float your 4 divs next to C.
it will look something like this:

```
<div class="wrapper col-6">
    <div class="A"></div>
    <div class="B"></div>
    <div class="D"></div>
    <div class="E"></div>
</div>
<div class="C col-6"></div>
```

Add your responsive columns as needed

Comment: This worked and uses less code. Thanks! Gotta hate when those mental blocks hit you...

Answer (score 1):

Simply create two separate columns. A floating left with the four boxes and another to the right with a single box. See the solution in this link http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqOxaW

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="col-md-4 noBox" id="div1">A</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 noBox" id="div2">B</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 noBox" id="div4">D</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 noBox" id="div5">E</div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="col-md-4 noBox" id="div3">C</div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
#div1 {background-color: red;}
#div2 {background-color: green;}
#div3 {background-color: blue;}
#div4 {background-color: yellow;}
#div5 {background-color: pink;}
#div6 {background-color: cyan;}

.container {
width: 400px;
display: table;
}

.container .left {
width: 200px;
float: left;
}

.container .left > div {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
float: left;
}

.container .right {
width: 100px;
float: right;
}

.container .right > div {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
float: right;
}

body {
background-color: black;
}

.noBox {
line-height: 100px;
color: white;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
}

#div3 {line-height: 200px;}

</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tackled the same problem (different layout) using the core Bootstrap 3 CSS so it is still responsive. The example above isn't responsive.

See [Codeply here](http://www.codeply.com/go/71rS136sxJ) where I placed this code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">            
        <div class="col-md-12" id="BigBox">
            <div class="col-md-6" id=LeftBigBox><p>Left box copy</p></div>                
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6" id="TopBox"><p>Top right box copy</p></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6" id="BottomBox"><p>Bottom right box copy</p></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>       
    </div>
</div>
```